# HAML nesting tags

Tags: haml

I'm trying to nest this

```
  %h1 Admin Menu
    %small logged in as: #{session[:username]}
```

To get something like this

```
<h1>Admin Menu <small>logged in as: something</small></h1>
```

But the only way I can get it to display without firing an error is putting them at the same level, say

```
  %h1 Admin Menu
  %small logged in as: #{session[:username]}
```

Which outputs:

```
<h1>Admin Menu</h1>
<small>logged in as: something</small>
```

It's probaby something silly but I have no idea this why this wouldn't work?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Haml only allows inline nesting if everything that will be nested is inline. So you can do this:

```
%h1 Admin Menu
```

or this:

```
%h1
  Admin Menu
  %small logged in as: #{session[:username]}
```

but not this:

```
 %h1 Admin Menu
   %small logged in as: #{session[:username]}
```

The first form should really be thought of as a convenient abbreviation. It exists so you can take something like this:

```
%li
  One
%li
  Two
%li
  Three
```

and just say:

```
%li One
%li Two
%li Three
```

Answer (score 7):

I haven't tried, but won't the following work for you?

```
%h1 
  Admin Menu
  %small logged in as: #{session[:username]}
```

Answer (score 1):

The other trick is this.

```
%h1 
  Admin Menu
  %small
    logged in as: 
    =session[:username]
```

because last 2 lines will be rendered inside "small"-tag

Answer (score 0):

Or you could just use simple css to do the trick, as:

```
%h1
  Admin Menu
    .small{ style: 'font-size: smaller;' }
      logged in as:
      = session[:username]
```

this way you can specify other attributes or the specific size of the font.

Comment: In this case the <small> tag was just an example but I would like to do nesting of other tags too, thank you for the tip tho.